# Different keyword in sql

Tags: sql-server

What is 'PROBLEM:' keyword in sql?

How to use it?

Basically I have seen  this keyword in a sql query. But whenever I going to search about this keyword, then everyone posted a reply to get rid from problem in sql. But the main problem is, I failed to make understand to others that, "Problem:" is a keyword.

And this is the main problem. So can anyone describe about this keyword

Comment: Do you have a link to where you encountered that "keyword"? Are you sure it is a keyword? I am not, because it does not show in the list of reserved keywords: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: You probably _think_ it is a keyword because it is highlighted blue when typed in SSMS?

Comment: What is your PROBLEM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word preceding a colon is a label used by `goto` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx)

"PROBLEM" is not a [reserved word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Comment: Thanks you for your valuable answer. Now I can understand that matter.
Actually that keyward was written in a stored procedure. I couldn't understand the logic of that keyword.